# Extract substrings from regex in Java

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
\w* is part of \w*
```

and this string:

```
XXX is part of ZZZZZ
```

I need extract XXX and ZZZZZ only by match with substitutive part.
Or:

```
next example \w* \w*

next example qwer tuip
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `by match with substitutive part.` ? what is the meaning of this ?

Comment: `str = "XXX is part of ZZZZZ";` `str.replaceAll("\\^.*(is part of).*\\$", "qwer $1 tuip");`

Comment: what is under: \w*
You dont know if there is (is part of) or something else, som it wont be work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Wrapping the part of your regex that you want to capture in parentheses will allow you to retrieve it:

```
(\w*) is part of (\w*)
```

Let's say you have the same example string `XXX is part of ZZZ` and want to get the values `XXX` and `ZZZ`.

To retrieve them, we'll say you have a `Matcher matcher`, you'd call:

```
String xxx = matcher.group(1); //Value will be "XXX"
String zzz = matcher.group(2); //Value will be "ZZZ"
```

(The captured groups are indexed starting at 1; `group(0)` is the entire string matching the regex.)